# What is the meaning of the phrase: "you will be gathered unto your people," mentioned by the passing of Moshe and Aharon?

Tags: torah-reading, moshe-rabbeinu

The phrase arises as follows:

Numbers 27:13

> וראיתה אתה ונאספת אל עמיך גם אתה כאשר נאסף אהרן אחיך
>
> And when thou hast seen it, thou also shalt be gathered unto thy
> people, as Aaron thy brother was gathered

Numbers 20:24

> יאסף אהרן אל עמיו כי לא יבא אל הארץ אשר נתתי לבני ישראל על אשר מריתם
> את פי למי מריבה
>
> Aaron shall be gathered unto his people; for he shall not enter into
> the land which I have given unto the children of Israel, because ye
> rebelled against My word at the waters of Meribah.

This cannot mean that the Jews will gather him and bury him because God himself buried Moshe.

Answer (score 2):

[Or HaChaim on Deuteronomy 32:50](https://www.sefaria.org/Or_HaChaim_on_Deuteronomy.32.50.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> G'd added והאסף אל עמיך, "and be gathered in to your people," this is an allusion to what the Talmud says in Ketuvot 104 that the righteous in the hereafter come out to welcome the righteous who is about to join them. G'd told Moses he was going to be met by a reception committee.

Answer (score 0):

I believe various rabbis or maybe even the Gemara use this as proof that the soul is eternal and there is some sort of afterlife. So, Moshe and Aaron won’t just die, rather they’ll be gathered to the rest of the would of previous Jews who have died

Comment: thanks for the answer. Sources are strongly encouraged on this forum when answering a question.

Comment: are you referring to the use of the phrase וַיֵּאָסֶף אֶל עַמָּיו? That is used for Avraham and Yitzchak also. For Avraham in Ber 25:8 the Ibn Ezra writes, "AND WAS GATHERED TO HIS PEOPLE. Some say that this refers to the soul of life which, even while functioning in the body, is a separate entity. When it separates from the body it returns to its source. Others say that and was gathered to his people is a mere idiom. One who follows in the footsteps of his ancestors is said, as it were, to be joining them. But thou shalt go to thy fathers in peace (Gen. 15:15) is similar." via sefaria